# Populating ListView with NavigationParameters?

Tags: ios, xaml, listview, xamarin, prism

In my Xamarin Forms application, I have a ListView with different cells, using DataTemplates and DataTemplateSelectors. For one type of cell, it has a button on it, which when tapped, navigates to another page  which contains just a ListView which is made up of only strings.

My problem arises from the OnNavigatedTo method being called after the page has loaded, and therefore the list that I am passing to this new 'ListView only' page, updates the value that I bind the ListView to after the ListView is created and populated, but it is populated with nothing because the data comes from the previous page via the OnNavigatedTo method.

```
public class ListPageViewModel : _ViewModelBase
{
    private INavigationService _navigationService;

    public ListPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
        _strings = new List<string>()
        {
            "Jaguar", "Elephant", "Nemo", "Cat", "Dog", "Iguana", "Puma", "Crow", "Hawk", "Owl", "Badger", "Meerket",
            "Shark", "Whale", "Monkey", "Snake", "Lion", "Zebra", "Hippo", "Squirrel", "Rhino", "Bear", "Moose",
            "Camel", "Chicken", "Cow", "Sheep", "Turkey", "Jellyfish", "Salmon", "Parrot", "Wolf", "Gecko"
            // Placeholder before we have lists of customers
        };
    }

    private IEnumerable<string> _strings;
    public IEnumerable<string> Strings { get { return _strings; } set { SetProperty(ref _strings, value); } }

    public override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(parameters);

        if (parameters.ContainsKey("dataList"))
        {
            _strings = (List<string>)parameters["dataList"];
        }
    }
}
```

So when I navigate to this page, the `_strings` list is first populated with the list of animals, and then the page loads showing all the animals in the ListView, and then after the ListView has loaded it changes the value of the `_strings` list to be the same as the list passed along with the NavigationParameters. So how do I make the ListView update every time the `_strings` list is changed or updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either

```
Strings = (List<string>)parameters["dataList"];
```

or use an `ObservableCollection`